# How do I append a Python object attribute (list)

Tags: python, list, object, attributes, append

I would like to write a function to append an attribute of a Python object, the attribute is a list.

Here is my code, which sets the attribute to a given value. Is there a simpler/cleaner way to this..

```
class Obj(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 2
        self.b = []
        self.c = []

    def append_att(self, att):
        at = getattr(self, att)
        at.append(self.a)
        setattr(self,att, at)
obj = Obj()
obj.append_att('b')
obj.append_att('b')
print obj.b
```

Comment: This looks like an XY problem, what are you trying to actually achieve?

Comment: FWIW, you could simply do: `getattr(self, att).append(self.a)`

Comment: Why are you doing `setattr(self,att, at)`?

Comment: `Explicit is better than implicit!` You would normally do `getattr(obj, 'b').append(obj.a)` without defining any methods. `self.b` holds reference to the `list` instance and you don't have to reassign it. Modification to the list is transparently seen by `self.b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `self.__dict__` to append to the list with the same string variable name as the value to be added to the list:

```
class Obj(object):
   def __init__(self):
      self.a = 2
      self.b = []
      self.c = []
   def append_att(self, att):
      self.__dict__[att].append(self.a)

o = Obj()
o.append_att('b')
o.append_att('b')
o.append_att('c') 
print(o.b)
print(o.c)
```

Output:

```
[2, 2]
[2]
```